# How to get local client ip in nginx that is behind cloudflare (already got public ip)

Tags: nginx, cloudflare

I have ngnix proxying to a nodejs server. I am trying to read the request client local ip address in my nginx, my nginx is behind cloudflare
i tried this :
`req.headers['x-local-ip']`
but it is always showing the public ip adress same as req.headers['x-local-ip']

i tried adding it to nginx but in my access log it doesnt show local ip , only public ip , even if i read the x-local-ip i find public ip , i tried to inspect in chrome and i found out that the local and public ip are the same in the header